# Enabling client certificate passthrough without validation

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to configure nginx-ingress for Kubernetes so that client certificate is passed on to backend service without validation.

Due to customer requests we are using client certificates for authentication but the certificates are not signed by the server and as such it's not really our job to validate the certificate, only to check that it is on the allowed certificates list.

Things work well on our test server where we use certificates signed by the servers CA certificate but after setting

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "off"
```

the client certificate is no longer forwarded in request header even though we still have

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "true"
```

Does nginx-ingress even allow passing through client certificates without validation?

I expected that disabling auth-tls-verify-client would just stop nginx-ingress from validating the certificate signature and still pass it through, but instead it disappeared from the request.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest looking at [this issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/3511)

> When adding auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: true to an ingress resource, the client certificate passed to the ingress controller is not forwarded to the backend pod.

Apparently, the issues was

> the issue to be more around standardization of passing client certificates in headers. I've found nginx is passing the client cert to the backend pod in the Ssl-client-certificate header.

In your case, I would suggest checking all the header values for the certificate, and see if it is there under a different name.

On top of this, remember to check that you **start the nginx ingress controller with flag `enable-ssl-passthrough`

Comment: I suggest you show most of the solution inside the body of the answer, rather than referring to an external source